# How to use DELETE and keep referential integrity?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables such that:

```
CREATE TABLE guest(

name varchar(100),
ranking int,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE room(

 roomname varchar(100),
 wallcolor varchar(100),
 rating int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomnane)
 );

 CREATE TABLE reservation(

 name varchar(100),
 roomname varchar(100),
 day varchar(100),
 moveinday int,
 moveoutday int,
 PRIMARY KEY(roomname, day, start, finish),
  FOREIGN KEY(roomname) REFERENCES room(roomname),
  FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES guest(name)
 );
```

I am trying to write a DELETE query to delete all the guests that are not qualified to rent a room.  Qualified to rent means the guests ranking is greater than or equal to room ranking.

I tried

```
DELETE FROM guest, reservations
WHERE guest.ranking<  rooms.ranking
```

This seems to violate the referential integrity from reservation to guest tables. How could I fix this?

Comment: Problem is that lets say `guest1` has lower rank than `room1` but higher than `room2`. if you delete `guest1` referencial integrity will be violated in  reservation table (for `room2` `guest1` row).

Comment: tchelidze is right. In this case you have to decide whether you would delete that particular guest although he might have other valid reservations.

Comment: Instead of deleting the guest you should delete the corresponding reservation entries which violate your criteria

Comment: Do you or do you not want to delete the guest?

Answer (score 0):

**tchelidze highlighted a case:**

> Let's say guest 1 has lower rank than room1 but higher than room2. If
>   you delete guest1 then referential integrity will be violated in
>   reservation table (for room2 guest1 row).

I think you should not delete the guest entry. Because that particular guest might have other valid reservations.

[So if you delete that guest you might lose your potential customer. Great loss! :p]

**Instead of deleting the guest you should delete the corresponding reservation entries which violate your criteria.**

That's what I am trying to do.

**I am gonna delete all reservations where guest ranking is lower than room ranking but not the guest itself.**

***So here's the query:***

```
DELETE reservation
FROM
    reservation
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        reservation.roomname,
        reservation.day,
        reservation.start,
        reservation.finish
    FROM
        guest
    INNER JOIN reservation ON reservation.name = guest.name
    INNER JOIN room ON reservation.roomname = room.roomname
    WHERE
        room.rating > guest.ranking
) invalidReservationTable 
ON reservation.roomname = invalidReservationTable.roomname
AND reservation.day = invalidReservationTable.day
AND reservation.start = invalidReservationTable.start
AND reservation.finish = invalidReservationTable.finish
```

**Explanation:**

[image]

Comment: How does this work? You are deleting the whole reservation table?

Comment: No I am not deleting the whole reservation table. `DELETE tableA FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.value = tableB.value. This particular query will delete the entries from tableA which match the corresponding entries in tableB. Not the whole tableA.`